# Why is defaultSelectedKeys in ant-design Menu component not reading react state changes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, menu, antd

please help me.
I have a problem with the ant-design Menu component, where the menu doesn't read the state changes that occur.

Here I simulate, when the button is clicked it will change the defaultSelectedKeys based on the select state value, but defaultSelectedKeys doesn't change.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppstoreOutlined, MailOutlined, SettingOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import type { MenuProps } from 'antd';
import { Menu } from 'antd';

type MenuItem = Required<MenuProps>['items'][number];

function getItem(
  label: React.ReactNode,
  key: React.Key,
  icon?: React.ReactNode,
  children?: MenuItem[],
  type?: 'group',
): MenuItem {
  return {
    key,
    icon,
    children,
    label,
    type,
  } as MenuItem;
}

const items: MenuProps['items'] = [
  getItem('Navigation One', 'sub1', <MailOutlined />, [
    getItem('Item 1', 'g1', null, [getItem('Option 1', '1'), getItem('Option 2', '2')], 'group'),
    getItem('Item 2', 'g2', null, [getItem('Option 3', '3'), getItem('Option 4', '4')], 'group'),
  ]),

  getItem('Navigation Two', 'sub2', <AppstoreOutlined />, [
    getItem('Option 5', '5'),
    getItem('Option 6', '6'),
    getItem('Submenu', 'sub3', null, [getItem('Option 7', '7'), getItem('Option 8', '8')]),
  ]),

  { type: 'divider' },

  getItem('Navigation Three', 'sub4', <SettingOutlined />, [
    getItem('Option 9', '9'),
    getItem('Option 10', '10'),
    getItem('Option 11', '11'),
    getItem('Option 12', '12'),
  ]),

  getItem('Group', 'grp', null, [getItem('Option 13', '13'), getItem('Option 14', '14')], 'group'),
];

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [select, setSelect] = React.useState(['3'])
  const onClick: MenuProps['onClick'] = (e) => {
    console.log('click ', e);
  };

  return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Menu
      onClick={onClick}
      style={{ width: 256 }}
      defaultSelectedKeys={select}
      defaultOpenKeys={['sub1']}
      mode="inline"
      items={items}
    />
{/*
update state here
*/}
    <button onClick={() =>{setSelect(['2'])}}>click</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[Here the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By2yZ.png)

expect:
when the button is clicked. then the active menu is option 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use selectedKeys instead of defaultSelectedKeys.

```
<Menu
      onClick={onClick}
      style={{ width: 256 }}
      selectedKeys={select}
      mode="inline"
      items={items}
    />
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. I was wrong, props should use selectedKeys like you said